# Как форматировать длительное время?

Tags: javascript

Например есть переменная `let d = "5:00"`

и ему надо возвращать значение в функции секунды

Comment: Можете переформулировать и показать исходную строку и то, что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос, нажав кнопку править под сообщением. Уточните вопрос, что именно вам нужно сделать.

Comment: @OliverPatterson что непонятно? Минуты превращаем в секунды, а секунды оставляем как есть и суммируем.

Comment: @ΝNL993, лично мне сложно было понять вопрос. Прочитвав ваш комментарий, теперь реально можно так прочитать вопрос)

Comment: Это также могли быть `Часы:Минуты`... Да все что угодно! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы реализовал как-то так.

```js
const time = "5:31";

console.info(timeToSeconds(time));

function timeToSeconds(time)
{
  return time.split(":").reduce((acc, time) => (60 * acc) + Number(time));
}
```